# Confused about libraries libtorrent and Deluge

Tags: linux, debian, python, libraries, deluge

So i have a remote Debian 7 Server that i am managing and I am still learning a lot about Debian and Linux in general.

To be specific i have the following questions:

1) How do i determine what library is being used for Deluge? I have installed Deluge 1.3.6 from source as well as libtorrent-rasterbar-0.15.10.
When i run the deluge -v command i get the :
$ deluge -v
deluge: 1.3.6
libtorrent: 0.15.10.0

Shown to me, is there a way to determine what library is being used in a different way inside linux?

2) When i run dpkg -S libtorrent i get the following:

> $ dpkg -S libtorrent
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.6
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/share/doc/libtorrent-rasterbar6/copyright
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.6.0.0
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/share/pyshared/python_libtorrent-0.15.10.egg-info
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/share/doc/python-libtorrent/changelog.Debian.gz
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/share/doc/libtorrent-rasterbar6
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libtorrent.so
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/libtorrent.so
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/share/doc/python-libtorrent/copyright
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/share/doc/libtorrent-rasterbar6/README.Debian
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/share/doc/python-libtorrent/changelog.gz
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/python_libtorrent-0.15.10.egg-info
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/share/doc/libtorrent-rasterbar6/changelog.Debian.gz
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.6/libtorrent.so
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/share/doc/libtorrent-rasterbar6/AUTHORS
>   libtorrent-rasterbar6: /usr/share/doc/libtorrent-rasterbar6/changelog.gz
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/share/doc/python-libtorrent
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libtorrent.so
>   python-libtorrent: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_libtorrent-0.15.10.egg-info

I would like to know/understand the difference between these, if i installed and binded rasterbar why is rasterbar shown as libtorrent-rasterbar6 instead of rasterbar0.15.10.

Im just generally a bit confused would appreciate some input here :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ldd, ldd on binary files display library requirement of that file.
for example, this is library requirement of echo on my box:

```
#ldd /bin/echo
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff441fe000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4a5a715000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4a5aae8000)
```